# Does Joh 14:26 speak to assumptions about hermeneutics?

Tags: john, hermeneutical-approaches

> Joh 14:26 But the Comforter, [which is] the Holy Ghost, whom the
>   Father will send in my name, he shall teach you all things, and bring
>   all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you.

Speaking of inerrancy, some make the assumption that what God intended was to teach us of salvation, and all the other details were chosen by the human authors and may be erroneous.

Jesus tells his disciples that the Father will send the Holy Ghost to:

1. Teach them **all** things.
2. Remind them of **whatsoever** he taught them

Furthermore, the scriptures warn us of prophets who teach lies:

> Isa 9:15 The ancient and honourable, he [is] the head; and the prophet
>   that teacheth lies, he [is] the tail.

A lie is a lie whether one knows that they are lying or not. Such is the potential harm of repeating gossip. So if the apostles taught things which are not true, knowingly or not, then they are false prophets. If the apostles were not sure that what they taught was true,  they would have have preferred not to teach it.

The assumption then, also presupposes that the apostles were incompetent to determine truth from error, and places their whole testimony in jeopardy.

What indication is there that **all** and **whatsoever** should be interpreted as hyperbole such that we may assume that the apostles don't know what they are talking about?

Comment: Who are you including in "the apostles"? Do we even know what most of the 12 did after the day of Pentecost?

Comment: Are you implying that denying biblical inerrancy is equivalent to calling the apostles liars?

Comment: I think I intended to say that the authors of the gospels took their task seriously, and if they had any doubt about the factual nature of something they would have preferred to leave it out. Therefore, they believed it to be true. If they thought falsehoods were true, then their ability to discern truth is placed in jeopardy.  Either way, it places doubt on the truthful nature of all of their testimony. What hermeneutic can be applied to tell when they knew what they were talking about and when they didn't?

Comment: I don't think there is any evidence that the gospel writers would always have left out details whenever there was any doubt. Compare, for example, the differences among the gospels in 1) the words exchanged between Jesus and John at Jesus' baptism, 2) the names of the twelve apostles, 3) the words exchanged between Jesus and Pilate at Jesus' trial, 4) the identities of the people who questioned Peter before the cock crowed, 5) the women who accompanied Mary to the tomb. There is considerable disagreement on the details, yet they all agree on the big picture, which is what really counts.

Comment: Sure, the gospel writers took their task seriously. However, they did not write the gospels to communicate the history of Jesus, but rather the *meaning* of Jesus.

Comment: I understand that is your presupposition. The question asks what the justification for it is so that we can understand the scripture above in context. One way to 'resolve' apparent contradiction is to make the assumptions you do, another way is to presume that they are not contradictions and accept plausible answers. A third way is to assume they are intentional riddles.  If there is no indication that we should accept it as hyperbole, you can just write it off as another error because of your presupposition, or by defining terms. For you truth = salvific truth.

Comment: This question seems overly confrontational and rhetorical.  If this were your first question, I'd probably overlook it and try to answer earnestly.  But I find myself having the same reaction to each of your questions.  How can we convince you to write better, more approachable questions?

Comment: @Jon, by rewriting it in a non-confronational way that I can mimic. It is exactly the same question I have asked Mormons for 30 years when they have excuses for not believing what the Bible says.  If we say that the Bible doesn't mean what it says, or has errors, etc. we need to be able to answer it as well.  I thought we were looking for difficult questions. Please show me how to retain the question and make it non-confrontational.

Comment: @Jon, I have been a evangelist in Utah for 30 years. We used to get multiple death threats every week. We started Bible studies in communities where there were no Christian churches, and when people got saved they had to move out of town because no one would do business with them. I would preach in four to five communities in a week.  It is my nature as an evangelist to ask pointed, direct, confrontational questions to get quickly to the point with someone on the street or bus or library. I don't mind if you wish to edit the questions more to your liking. I thought you wanted lots of questions

Comment: BTW, you don't know what confrontational is until you get some KJ only in here.  One pastor pays his tithe with his right hand and keeps his left hand in his pocket because we are not supposed to let the left hand know what the right is doing. And anyone doing otherwise is sinning. I think it fair to ask for the foundational presumptions of his hermeneutic as well.

Comment: Well, this is my best shot.  Most of the work was actually cutting words that don't (in my opinion) help you get the meaning of your question across.  I also picked the ESV, which will help an average reader understand the passage better.  As always, feel free to re-edit.

Comment: I think the meaning is completely changed. The way it is now can be answered yes or no.  I was shooting for an explanation of the hermeneutical principles used to reconcile apparent contradictions within the framework.  It is no longer a question for experts and merely elicits opinions.  There is no tension in the question, so there is nothing to resolve. You'll have enough boring questions without having to neuter mine  ;-)

Comment: Have any traffic studies been done on confrontational vs castrated questions?

Comment: @Bob: As I say, feel free to re-edit.  (You may even rollback to your original question.)  I may be wrong, but I don't think we care about traffic enough (in the short term) to ask confrontational questions that will set the wrong tone for the community (in the long run).  The site will be best served by the tortoise's strategy.  We are not going to be in for a pleasant time together if you insist on asking overly-confrontational questions.  I hope you'll reconsider.

Comment: It your site, do what you want with it.

Comment: @Bob: It isn't _my_ site.  It's _our_ site.  You are part of _our_ at this point.  (And I hope for a good long time to come.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to attempt an answer at this even though I'm not entirely clear on the question or the assumptions beneath it.

I don't think that Jesus is directly addressing general hermeneutic principles, nor anything specific to the gospels, for three reasons:

1. The identities of the authors
2. The nature of the gospels
3. The purposes of the authors

### The identities of the authors

In this passage, Jesus was directly addressing the disciples - those who would eventually be known as the apostles.  Yet, according to generally accepted authorship, only two of the four gospels were written by disciples.  Likewise, half of the New Testament was written by someone who wasn't even present at this time and who would ultimately be a deadly opponent to the church during its early years prior to his amazing conversion.  As near as we can tell, disciples only wrote 8 of the 27 books in the New Testament, and, except for Matthew, John and Revelation, they tend to be fairly short, focused doctrinal works.  (And the authorship of some of those 8 is disputed.)

### The nature of the gospels

Jesus does *not* seem to be instructing the disciples that they were to exhaustively document His words and ministry.  Otherwise, they would have written significantly more than they did about His ministry.  In fact, even John himself [noted that he did not exhaustively document](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Jn21.24-25/) Jesus' ministry.  If he had thought this was Jesus' command, wouldn't he have chosen to do so?

### The purposes of the authors

Each of the gospel authors had a particular focus or goal in their writing.  So yes, to some extent they picked and chose specific events.  However, that does not mean that their witness is unreliable.  John's purpose was to point out Jesus as the Messiah, so he didn't bother to include events such as the Sermon on the Mount because it didn't really match his purpose to do so.  On the flip side, he included some events that the other gospels didn't, so presumably they left them out for the same reason.

Comment: Good job.  Then what is the basis for inerrancy if not this passage or ones like it. It seems like circular reasoning to say that we believe it is inerrant because it is scripture, but we decided it was scripture.  So it is inerrant because we said so.

Comment: I don't think *THIS* passage necessarily has anything to do with inerrancy, because Jesus wasn't focusing on their writings.  Most people I've seen tackle that do so from 2 Timothy 3:16 or 2 Peter 1:21.  (In fact, see all of 2 Peter 1:16-21.)